# Can someone explain Linux library naming?

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

When I create a library on Linux, I use this method:

1. Build: libhelloworld.so.1.0.0
2. Link: libhelloworld.so.1.0.0 libhelloworld.so
3. Link: libhelloworld.so.1.0.0 libhelloworld.so.1

The versioning is so that if you change the public facing methods, you can build to libhelloworld.so.2.0.0 for example (and leave 1.0.0 where it is), so that applications using the old library won't break.

However, what's the point in naming it 1.0.0 - why not just stick with libhelloworld.so and libhelloworld.so.1?

**Also**, is it best practice to name your library using 1.0.0 for example, or just 1?

```
g++ ... -Wl,-soname,libhelloworld.1
```

Or:

```
g++ ... -Wl,-soname,libhelloworld.1.0.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From an old email I sent to a colleague about this question:

Let's look at libxml as an example.  First of all, shared
objects are stored in /usr/lib with a series of symlinks to represent
the version of the library availiable:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 Apr  4  2002 libxml.so -> libxml.so.1.8.14
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 Apr  4  2002 libxml.so.1 -> libxml.so.1.8.14
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 498438 Aug 13  2001 libxml.so.1.8.14
```

If I'm the author of libxml and I come out with a new version, libxml
2.0.0 that breaks interface compatiblity with the previous version, I
can install it as libxml.so.2, and libxml.so.2.0.0.  Note that it is
up to the application programmer to be responsible about what he links
to.  If I'm really anal, I can link directly to libxml.so.1.8.14 and
any other version will result in my program not running.  Or I can
link against libxml.so.1 and hope that the libxml developer doesn't
break symbol compatibility on me in the 1.X version.  Or if you don't
care and are reckless, just link to libxml.so and get whatever version
there is.  Sometimes, when enough people do this, the library author
has to get creative with later versions.  Hence, libxml2:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     17 Apr  4  2002 libxml2.so.2 -> libxml2.so.2.4.10
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 692727 Nov 13  2001 libxml2.so.2.4.10
```

Note that there's no libxml2.so in this one.  Looks like the developer
got fed up with irresponsible application developers.

Comment: Umm, false.  When you give `-lxml` to the dynamic linker, it will use the *library soname* in `libxml.so`, which would be `libxml.so.1`, so that's what the generated executable links against.  ...(continued)

Comment: (continued)...  Linking directly to `libxml.so` or `libxml.so.1.8.14` *does not* happen when the library is properly versioned.  The `lib*.so` symlink is not needed for running executables, only developing them, so you may find that they are often placed in separate binary packages.

Comment: To see the library soname, use `readelf -d /usr/lib/libxml.so` (assuming you're on a development system with binutils installed).

Answer (score 24):

### Library naming conventions

According to [Wheeler](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html), we have the `real name`, the `soname` and the `linker name`:

```
  Real name  libfoo.so.1.2.3
     Soname  libfoo.so.1
Linker name  libfoo.so
```

The `real name` is the name of the file containing the actual library code. The `soname` is usually a symbolic link to the `real name`, and its number is incremented when the interface changes in an incompatible way. Finally, the `linker name` is what the linker uses when requesting a library, which is the soname without any version number.

So, to answer your last question first, you should use the `soname`, `libhelloworld.so.1`, for the linker option [when creating the shared library](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html#AEN95):

```
g++ ... -Wl,-soname,libhelloworld.so.1 ...
```

[In this document](http://man7.org/conf/lca2006/shared_libraries/slide6.html), Kerrisk provides a very brief example on how to create a shared library using standard naming conventions. I think both [Kerrisk](http://man7.org/conf/lca2006/shared_libraries/index.html) and [Wheeler](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) are well worth a read if you want to know more about Linux libraries.

### Library numbering conventions

There is some confusion regarding the intent and purpose of each of the numbers in the `real name` of the library. I personally think that the [Apache Portable Runtime Project](http://apr.apache.org/versioning.html) does a good job of explaining the rules for when each number should be incremented.

In short, the versioning numbers can be thought of as `libfoo.MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH`.

- `PATCH` is incremented for changes that are both forwards and backwards compatible with other versions.
- `MINOR` should be incremented if the new version of the library is source and binary compatible with the old version. Different minor versions are backwards compatible, but not necessarily forwards compatible, with each other.
- `MAJOR` is incremented when a change is introduced that breaks the API, or is otherwise incompatible with the previous version.

What this means is that `PATCH` releases may only differ internally, for example in the way a function is implemented. Changing the API, the signature of public functions, or the interpretation of function parameters is **not allowed**.

A new `MINOR` release may introduce new functions or constants, and deprecate existing functions, but **may not remove** anything that is  externally exposed. This ensures *backwards compatibility*. In other words, a minor release `1.12.3` may be used to replace any other `1.12.x` *or earlier* version, such as `1.11.2` or `1.5.0`. It is not a drop in replacement for `1.16.1` though, since different minor versions are not necessarily *forward compatible*.

Any kind of change can be made with the release of a new `MAJOR` version; constants may be removed or changed, (deprecated) functions may be removed, and of course, any changes that would normally increment the `MINOR` or `PATCH` number (though it might be worth it to backport such changes to the previous `MAJOR` version also).

Of course, there are factors that can complicate this further; you might have developed your library so that the same file may [hold multiple versions simultaneously](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://people.redhat.com/drepper/dsohowto.pdf&embedded=true#:0.page.36), or you might use `libtool`'s convention of `current:revision:age`. But that's a discussion for another time. :)

Answer (score 22):

The way you're supposed to form the x.y.z version  is like this:

1. The first number (x) is the interface version of the library. Whenever you change the public interface, this number goes up.
2. The second number (y) is the revision number of the current interface. Whenever you make an internal change without changing the public interface, this number goes up.
3. The third number (z) is **not** a build number, it is the backwards-compatability count. This tells you how many *previous* interfaces are supported. So for example if interface version 4 is strictly a  superset of interfaces 3 and 2, but totally incompatible with 1, then z=2 (4-2 = 2, the lowest interface number supported)

So the x and z numbers are very important for the system to determine if a given app can use a given library, given what the app was compiled against. The y number is mainly for tracking bug fixes.

Comment: I think your explanation defines the libtool mapping scheme, not the Linux (or Solaris) soname scheme.

Answer (score 4):

The primary advantage of this method is easily letting users know which version of the library they have. For example, if I know a bug I'm getting was fixed in 1.0.4 I can easily check what version of the library I am linking against, and know if that's the right way to fix the bug.

This number is referred to as the "shared object version" or "soversion" and is part of the ELF binary standard. IBM has a good overview of ELF at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/power/library/pa-spec12/.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to name libs:

1. Solaris-style: .so -> .so.1
2. GNU style: .so -> .so.1 -> .so.1.2.3
3. Random: .so -> .so.1.2

See:

https://blogs.oracle.com/ali/entry/how_to_name_a_solaris
http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libtool.html#Versioning