# Confused about .so version and linking strategy when distributing a api library

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, version

We have been porting our Java API to C++, and creating a library file (.a file) for Linux. Our API has dependency on the boost framework and also on log4cxx. (We discussed with the first user for this, and they are okay with those dependencies).

When I compile a sample application which uses our library file, it is linking against .so files for the dependencies (libboost_system.so, libboost_thread.so, and liblog4cxx.so).  When the application runs, it needs to find the specific versioned file names for each of those .so files, e.g. liblog4cxx.so.10.

If the user is using a newer version of boost (for example), would s/he be able to link against their local version and run with that newer version (assuming bacwards compatibility)?  Is there some other way to deal with versions/dependencies like these (i.e. do you try to link in the external referenced libraries to your own library)?

Comment: how are you linking your new library file against boost - static or dynamic?

Comment: @emsworth: the command line is `-L$BOOST_ROOT -lboost_system` so I believe that defaults to dynamic?  This has been a process of trial and error, so I can't say that I have a clear approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the program can link to newer libraries with a compatible interface. The numbers in the filename encode the library Application Binary Interface (ABI).

FreeBSD's [handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/policies-shlib.html) has more information about library versioning. The basic rules are:

- Start from 1.0
- If there is a change that is backwards compatible, bump minor number (note that ELF systems ignore the minor number)
- If there is an incompatible change, bump major number

The linker will sort out the details to use the newest library version with a compatible interface. There is also more information available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663209/can-someone-explain-about-linux-library-naming?rq=1) on stackoverflow.