# Why curl in linux has different libraries symbolic linked

Tags: linux, libcurl

For what reason curl in linux has different native libraries named libcurl.so, libcurl.so.4, libcurl.so.4.5 in which libcurl.so and libcurl.so.4 are symbolic linked to libcurl.so.4.5

Can anyone mention the use case of it in my project i copied all three files. As I have copied it became to a regular file with same size for all 3 files

What is the reason of having three libraries with same content?

Can I link anyone of it and use anyone at runtime. Currency I Link libcurl and use use libcurl.so.4 at runtime. Is it correct or do I need to use the same what I linked while compilation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can someone explain about Linux library naming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663209/can-someone-explain-about-linux-library-naming)

Comment: I have gone through it and understood. But while compiling I Link curl dynamically by using "- Wl, - Dynamic - lcurl" . In the post it is mentioned as the soname (libcurl.so.4) will be used in runtime. How to link soname file while compilation

Answer (score 1):

4 is the ABI major version. That ABI is stable. All libcurl clients that use a newer libcurl are binary compatible with libcurl.so.4 and should successfully run although some new options may be unavailable.